# Could not set unknown property 'mainClassName' for root project

Tags: java, gradle

I am writing a spark application. With the following `build.gradle` file, I am getting an error as stated in the title when syncing gradle in Intellij Idea.

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

mainClassName = 'HelloSpark'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
....
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is because the property `mainClassName` is introduced by the gradle plugin `application`. Adding the `application` plugin fixed the error:

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'application'
}
```

Comment: dude you saved me

Comment: me to, never gona guess that